# Can't write to file more than once in MIPS?

Tags: string, file, input, mips

I'm currently trying to learn how to write to files, however I can't seem to write to a file more than once. How would I go about writing multiple strings to a file, or in this case, the same string more than once? Thanks.

```
.data
str_exit: .asciiz "test.txt"
str_data: .asciiz "This is a test!"
str_data_end:

.text

file_open:
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, str_exit
    li $a1, 1
    li $a2, 0
    syscall  # File descriptor gets returned in $v0
file_write:
    move $a0, $v0  # Syscall 15 requieres file descriptor in $a0
    li $v0, 15
    la $a1, str_data
    la $a2, str_data_end
    la $a3, str_data
    subu $a2, $a2, $a3  # computes the length of the string, this is really a constant
    syscall

    move $a0, $v0  # Syscall 15 requieres file descriptor in $a0
    li $v0, 15
    la $a1, str_data
    la $a2, str_data_end
    la $a3, str_data
    subu $a2, $a2, $a3  # computes the length of the string, this is really a constant
    syscall
file_close:
    li $v0, 16  # $a0 already has the file descriptor
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for over half an hour yet the minute I post a question I figure it out on my own. I was setting $a0 to $v0, which had the incorrect value in it as I used $v0 after the first syscall, meaning I had the incorrect value in $a0 :\